# running multiple ray Tuning in parallel using a search algorithm

Tags: python, hyperparameters, ray, optuna

I want to queue 200+ tuning jobs to my ray cluster, they each need to be guided by a search algorithm, as my actual objective function has 40+ parameters.

I can do this for a single job like this:

```
import ray
from ray import tune
from ray.tune import Tuner, TuneConfig
from ray.tune.search.optuna import OptunaSearch


ray.init()

def objective(config):
    ground_truth = [1,2,3,4]
    yhat = [i*config['factor'] + config['constant'] for i in range(4)]
    abs_err = [abs(gt - yh) for gt, yh in zip(ground_truth, yhat)]
    mae = sum(abs_err)/len(abs_err)

    tune.report(mean_accuracy = mae)

config = {
    'factor': tune.quniform(0,3,1),
    'constant': tune.quniform(0,3,1)
}

algo = OptunaSearch()

tuner = tune.Tuner(
    objective,
    tune_config=TuneConfig(
        metric="mean_accuracy",
        mode="min",
        search_alg=algo,
        num_samples=100
    ),
    param_space=config
)
results = tuner.fit()
```

This works and gives the desired result for 1 of the 200 jobs.

Now I want to queue up to 200 jobs from a single run of a single script:

As far as I understood the [documentation](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/api_docs/execution.html) this is how that should work:

```
import ray
from ray import tune


ray.init()

def objective(config):
    ground_truth = [1,2,3,4]
    yhat = [i*config['factor'] + config['constant'] for i in range(4)]
    abs_err = [abs(gt - yh) for gt, yh in zip(ground_truth, yhat)]
    mae = sum(abs_err)/len(abs_err)

    tune.report(mean_accuracy = mae)

config = {
    'factor': tune.quniform(0,3,1),
    'constant': tune.quniform(0,3,1)
}

experiments = []
for i in range(3):
    experiment_spec = tune.Experiment(
        name=f'{i}',
        run=objective,
        stop={"mean_accuracy": 0},
        config=config,
        num_samples=10
    )
    experiments.append(experiment_spec)

out = tune.run_experiments(experiments)
```

When I run this I get the message: `Running with multiple concurrent experiments. All experiments will be using the same SearchAlgorithm.`.

I need to be able to specify the search algorithm, but I don't understand how. Additionally, these experiments appear to be part of one large optimization `out` is a list of 30 objective objects. The parameter values chosen are from a `uniform` distribution, without the q. However all 30 values fall in the specified range.

I must've misunderstood the purpose of run_experiments, please help.